# PHP - Using string values from array as initializing and accessing keys for arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to use an array value as part of an object reference?

Lets say I have an array initialized:

```
$service_types = array(
  "long" => array(
    "ltco", "field_long_term_care_ombudsman"
  ),
);
```

and am creating a new stdClass object with a number of arrays as properties.  Is it possible to use

```
$service_type = $service_types["long"];
$resource->$service_type[1] = new array("value" => "somenewvalue");
```

If not, what would be an alternative to implement this sort of functionality?

Comment: I don't see any reason why not. Your syntax for variable variables looks sound. But you don't need `new array()`, just declare `array()`, as it's a language construct.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using this strategy, variable variable names are often a pain to read and debug in the long run and don't promote clean and reusable code. Although it's perfectly valid code, i wouldn't do that!